# Update using subquery in mysql scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql

Halo guys,

I have a problem during my time using mysql since I am new in this area. Basically, I have SQL query that I use to insert the data and I created the scheduler to insert it automatically. But, I don't know how to update the data since I use the subquery to insert the data. This is the query that I use to insert the data :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO InactiveStore (shop_id, merchant, shop, solution, last_transaction_date, inactive, last_modified)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(LEFT(Store.internal_shop_id,5)," ",MID(Store.internal_shop_id,6,5)," ",MID(Store.internal_shop_id,11,5)," ",RIGHT(Store.internal_shop_id,6)) AS "shop_id",
  Merchant.merchant_name AS "merchant",
  Store.shop_name AS "shop",
  Merchant.solution AS "solution", 
  DATE_FORMAT(MAX(enterprise_transaction.paymentDate), '%d-%M-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS "last_transaction_date",
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(MAX(enterprise_transaction.paymentDate))) AS "inactive",
  NOW() AS "last_modified"
FROM 
  Merchant
JOIN 
  Store
ON Merchant.merchant_id = Store.merchant_id
JOIN 
  enterprise_transaction
ON Store.internal_shop_id = enterprise_transaction.internal_shop_id
WHERE Merchant.is_deleted = FALSE
AND Store.shop_status = 'Active'
AND Store.internal_shop_id NOT IN
(SELECT internal_shop_id FROM enterprise_transaction WHERE order_status = 'SUCCESS' AND enterprise_transaction.created_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY))
AND enterprise_transaction.total_amount >= '1000'  
GROUP BY Merchant.merchant_name, Store.shop_name
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(MAX(enterprise_transaction.paymentDate))) DESC, Store.shop_name ASC;
```

Do you have any suggestion on how can I build some queries to update the data after the data was inserted into the database?

Comment: No difference what is a source for a query - a table or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO InactiveStore 
      (shop_id, merchant, shop, solution, last_transaction_date, inactive, last_modified)
```

with

```
UPDATE InactiveStore 
JOIN ( your subquery ) table_alias 
ON InactiveStore.colname=table_alias.colname 
/*all those you want to update*/
SET InactiveStore.colname1=table_alias.colname1, 
    InactiveStore.colname2=table_alias.colname2, 
    InactiveStore.colname3=table_alias.colname3, 
    InactiveStore.colname4=table_alias.colname4
WHERE InactiveStore.colname5='your condition';
```

Before that, you can do checking like:

```
SELECT InactiveStore.colname, table_alias.colname,
    InactiveStore.colname1, table_alias.colname1, 
    InactiveStore.colname2, table_alias.colname2, 
    InactiveStore.colname3, table_alias.colname3, 
    InactiveStore.colname4, table_alias.colname4
FROM InactiveStore 
JOIN ( your subquery ) table_alias 
ON InactiveStore.colname=table_alias.colname 
WHERE InactiveStore.colname5='your condition';
```

To see what you're updating.